# List of actions that uses WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

Tags: android, permissions

I was trying to make a toggle widget (like a control one) but i've seen that many of the things i wanted to do needs WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission (like GPS, Airplane mode 4.2+...).

So, is there a place where i can check what actions needs which permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the official android docs on Manifest permissions?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

(sent from phone)

Comment: yeah, but it only says like...

"Allows an application to read or write the secure system settings."
I would like something more explained like what kind of things use this permission.